# Sshfs on Beaglebone Black password with Ubuntu arm 3.14

Tags: ssh, password, sshfs

I'm trying to transfer a file to my Beaglebone Black using sshfs. I've installed Ubuntu Arm 3.14.

I can use `sudo sshfs 192.168.0.102:/ /mnt/sshfs` which pops up with `root@192.168.0.102's password:`, however, the password is not the UNIX password that I'm able to set up through the passwd command on the Beaglebone. I tried all sorts of generic passwords as well as the default for Ubuntu arm, which is "temppwd". Is this password something specific for the superuser? I know that the sudo password and su password are different and I can't login to su without using the command `sudo su` on the Beaglebone.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu, by default, there is no password for the root account. That means you can't use `su` to become root, and you can't log into the root account with a password.

The password on the root account is unrelated to the password for your account. When you use `sudo`, you type the password for your account, not the root password.

Furthermore, by default, Ubuntu forbids using a password to log into the root account, but allows logging into the root account with a key.

If you want to use SSHFS with root access, you'll need to create a key pair and add the public key to `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys`. Make sure that `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` contains the line `PermitRootLogin without-password`.